# How to isolate a BIND9 nameserver

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I want to temporarily isolate a nameserver.

I have a problem with the public view zones not replicating to the secondary nameserver (ns2) correctly, so I took the secondary off line.  The master nameserver (ns1) would correctly supply the public IP for a query from a public location but the secondary would incorrectly supply the private IP for the same query from a public location.  I have a possible solution, but while implementing it in the production DNS servers, when I first turn on the secondary server I would like it to not be queriable or queried except by me for testing.

Servers are Linux running BIND 9.11.4.

- Is it enough to comment out the "IN NS ns2.example.com" lines in the zone files on all nameservers?
- Or do I have to go everywhere and comment out the ns2 addresses in /etc/resolv.conf?
- Is there any other way address information leaks out to the world?

Thanks for the cool suggestions, I especially like the firewall idea.  However since I had already commented out the ns2 entries with:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/IN NS ns2.example.com/;; &/' nam*
```

I proceeded with that.  Also the firewall idea would make testing more laborious since a lot of the testing is from outside the firewall and I'd have to punch a holes in the firewall rule, and I'd have to figure out if that posed a problem for testing from any production servers.  Then undoing the change would be:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/;; IN NS ns2.example.com/IN NS ns2.example.com/' nam*
```

Initially I thought I'd have to update the zone serials to make the change in the NS list propagate, but just a reload was enough to change it.

To comment on another comment, I do use TSIG keys for the replication configuration.  I plan to ask about my replication problem in a separate post.  I was able to fix the replication problem, but it's kind of a hack, and I'd like to fix the underlying problem.

Comment: Leave your zone files intact and simply use a firewall to restrict access to port 53 on the secondary name server until you have corrected the mis configuration and you should be good.

Comment: This is not what you ask about, but regarding the problem of hitting the right views from your other nameserver(s), you probably want to use TSIG keys for matching these particular queries rather than IP-based matching.

Comment: As proposed by HermanB, firewall is a neat solution. Another proposal, if it's a vm, you could add a virtual nic and bind BIND9 to that interface only. The nic should be connect to and isolated vlan or vswitch, where an admin pc can have access to make the tests.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to take eg `ns2.example.com` out of the rotation from a DNS point of view you would have to remove that `NS` record both from the zone itself and from the delegation (through your registrar). Then wait until caches expire.

With that in mind, if this is something you need to happen immediately and/or if this will just be a brief outage, it might be better to just block traffic in the firewall while making your changes and validating the results.
(If there will be an extended outage you may want to do a combination of both if the alternative would otherwise be to keep serving incorrect data until the cached `NS` data expires.)

Regarding the original problem of doing zone transfers in combination with views, I would recommend using TSIG keys for matching the views for this purpose rather than IP-based matching.

Eg something like this on the server with the master zones:

```
view "internal" {
  match-clients { !key external; key internal; 10.0.1/24; };

  ...
};

view "external" {
  match-clients { !key internal; key external; any; };

  ...
};
```

Then you can select the view you want to hit by using either the `internal` key or the `external` key, without the IP address being a factor.
This is a pretty typical way of facilitating zone transfers in a multi-view setup.